# spark-sql throws error on executing simple sq query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark and trying to go through the spark-sql documentation at https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/sql-programming-guide.html#sql

When I execute the following

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people")
```

I see exception (pasted below)

As far as I know I do not think I need hive or mqsql to be configured for this but looking at the error I see that some db connection is missing. 
Could some one please help with this and let me know what am I missing?

Here is the details for the spark and scala

> scala = 2.12.10  spark and spark-sql = 3.0.0-preview

```
 spark.sparkContext.getConf.getAll
res1: Array[(String, String)] = Array((spark.driver.port,39137), (spark.driver.host,192.xxx.0.yyy), (spark.repl.class.uri,spark://192.xxx.0.yyy:39137/classes), (spark.executor.id,driver), (spark.app.id,local-1574231864129), (spark.app.name,Spark shell), (spark.sql.catalogImplementation,hive), (spark.repl.class.outputDir,/tmp/spark-bd45bbfd-c946-4055-a724-0d0588d1f0b5/repl-d3f06d03-5db8-4559-b7ae-070405fadaa4), (spark.jars,""), (spark.submit.pyFiles,""), (spark.submit.deployMode,client), (spark.ui.showConsoleProgress,true), (spark.master,local[2]), (spark.home,/usr/local/spark))
```

Exception:

```
WARN Query: Query for candidates of org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MDatabase and subclasses resulted in no possible candidates
The java type java.lang.Long (jdbc-type="", sql-type="") cant be mapped for this datastore. No mapping is available.
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: The java type java.lang.Long (jdbc-type="", sql-type="") cant be mapped for this datastore. No mapping is available.
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.RDBMSMappingManager.getDatastoreMappingClass(RDBMSMappingManager.java:1215)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.mapping.RDBMSMappingManager.createDatastoreMapping(RDBMSMappingManager.java:1378)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.AbstractClassTable.addDatastoreId(AbstractClassTable.java:392)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.ClassTable.initializePK(ClassTable.java:1087)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.ClassTable.preInitialize(ClassTable.java:247)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTable(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3118)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTables(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2909)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.addClassTablesAndValidate(RDBMSStoreManager.java:3182)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager$ClassAdder.run(RDBMSStoreManager.java:2841)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.AbstractSchemaTransaction.execute(AbstractSchemaTransaction.java:122)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.addClasses(RDBMSStoreManager.java:1605)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.addClass(AbstractStoreManager.java:954)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.getDatastoreClass(RDBMSStoreManager.java:679)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.RDBMSQueryUtils.getStatementForCandidates(RDBMSQueryUtils.java:408)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery.compileQueryFull(JDOQLQuery.java:947)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JDOQLQuery.compileInternal(JDOQLQuery.java:370)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1744)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithArray(Query.java:1672)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.execute(Query.java:1654)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.ensureDbInit(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql.<init>(MetaStoreDirectSql.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:127)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:421)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.$anonfun$databaseExists$1(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:221)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.globalTempViewManager(SharedState.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$catalog$2(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.globalTempViewManager(SessionCatalog.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.lookupRelation(SessionCatalog.scala:741)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$lookupTableFromCatalog(Analyzer.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:725)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$6.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:765)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$6.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:757)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$3(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp$(AnalysisHelper.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUp$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp$(AnalysisHelper.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:757)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:694)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:119)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:607)
    at $line37.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:29)
    at $line37.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:33)
    at $line37.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:35)
    at $line37.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $line37.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:39)
    at $line37.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $line37.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
    at $line37.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:45)
    at $line37.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:47)
    at $line37.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $line37.$read.<init>(<console>:51)
    at $line37.$read$.<init>(<console>:55)
    at $line37.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line37.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line37.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line37.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:745)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1021)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.$anonfun$interpret$1(IMain.scala:574)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.asContext$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:37)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:600)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:570)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:894)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:762)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:464)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:485)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: You look at documentation of spark version 2.2.1 but try to launch it on 3.0.0-preview. Try to rollback to version 2.2.1 it may helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Boris. I fixed the issue. Issue was with having right version of java for spark. 
Also I downgraded to 2.4.4 and java 8 to be at safer side